# NGINX rewrite url if specific domain and specific url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite url when users access specific domain with root (aka /) url.
So far I have:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name name1.com name2.com;

  location = / {
    # Well, I need this only for NAME2.COM (it should not rewrite NAME1.COM)
    rewrite name2.com/users/sign_in
  }
}
```

How do rewrite only for NAME2.COM. Sometimes NGINX syntax makes my stack overflow. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split your server block. See: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name name1.com;

  location = / {
    # no rewrite here
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name name2.com;

  location = / {
    # your rewrite here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd use `if`, like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name name1.com name2.com;

  location = / {
    if ($host = name2.com) {
      rewrite ^ /users/sign_in last;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason this answer is beautiful because the only place you can use if for is this. So this answer wins.